# Password validation for Google G Suite Users

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-workspace, freeradius, google-openid

This FreeRadius module authenticates an Azure AD user using his/her username & password based on OAuth2:
[free-radius-oauth2-perl](https://github.com/jimdigriz/freeradius-oauth2-perl/blob/8ffda3af53384be26a145b6cd9a317d1f803acd3/main.pm#L370)

I would like to achieve the same process but authenticating Google accounts instead. Specifically, Google accounts managed through GSuite (now: Workspace). For Azure, there is a "token_endpoint" URI which you can use to send the user's name and password and it will return a token if the user is valid and the password is correct.

For Google, I found this: [Google OAuth OpenID](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#validatinganidtoken)
But it states that the only implemented *grant_type* is ***authorization_code*** which is not what I need (I need ***password***)

I also looked at the [Admin SDK for Workspace](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users) but I only found a *signOut* method, not a *signIn* or similar.

Any idea how to validate that a Google account exists and its password is correct?